# The dimensions for Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups

How can I find out which is the dimension for $SU(n)$, $SO(3)$, etc? Can you explain me, please?

thanks

Comment: Differentiate their defining relations at the identity to get relations defining their Lie algebras.

Comment: @blue is there any way to obtain this dimensions? thanks

Comment: There is a table, when you just need the numbers : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Lie_groups

Comment: Maybe you should add some detail to avoid further close votes. Are you looking for the dimension of the Lie Algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of $\mathfrak u(n)$ the Lie Algebra of the unitary group is $n^2$, since you can choose $n^2$ parameters for a skew-hermitian matrix: $n$ imaginary on the diagonal, $\frac {n()n-1)}{2}$ real and  $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ imaginary for the upper triangle: $n+2\times\frac {n(n-1)}{2} = n+ n^2-n=n^2$

For $h\in \mathfrak {su} (n)$ you have to have a $\rm{trace}(h)=0$, so you give on parameter, resulting in a dimension of $n^2-1$.

For $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ you diagonal is empty and you are left with $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ imaginary entries for the upper triangle.

For [$\mathfrak{sp}(n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) there is an additional symmetry involved:

> $$
>     \Omega A + A^T \Omega = 0
> $$
>   where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$ and $Ω$ is the skew-symmetric matrix
>   $$
>     \Omega = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}. 
> $$

which results in a dimension $n(2n+1)$...